# Replace multi line text with another multi line text using the perl command

Tags: perl, yaml

Previously I was trying to do it with `sed` but found that `perl` is better suited for multi line find and replace. Simple strings work fine but when it comes to strings with special characters it is not working as expected.

I am trying to replace:

```
COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS:
- ''
```

with:

```
COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS:
- '/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes'
- '/edx/src/ti-theme/edx-platform'
```

Here is my current command that gives me a `quote>` on the terminal instead of finding and replacing.

```
perl -0007 -i -pe   's/COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS:\n- \'\'/COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS:\n- \'\/edx\/app\/edxapp\/edx-platform\/themes\'\n- \'\/edx\/src\/ti-theme\/edx-platform\'/igs'
```

Comment: Is that a part of a larger file, with similar lines in a specific format? Like YAML?

Comment: Yes, its part of a huge YAML file, I have to change several lines every time I reset the docker container.

Comment: I was going to suggest using YAML::PP, but then I noticed you're setting up a container, so the module would be less appropriate.

Comment: Why not just load the YAML file and change the data structure?

Comment: @Labeeb In that case, you should definitely use a YAML parser instead of hacking your own regex. You're likely to risk breaking your data.

Comment: @briandfoy This becomes repetitive and prone to mistakes, I want a script that does the job so I do not have to spend time editing and verifying my changes.

Comment: @Labeeb I believe that brian did not mean that you should manually edit the file. He meant use a YAML parser to load the data into Perl, in a data structure, then edit the data and print it back to YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
perl -g -pe 's/COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS:\n- \047\047/COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS:\n- \047\/edx\/app\/edxapp\/edx-platform\/themes\047\n- \047\/edx\/src\/ti-theme\/edx-platform\047/igs' file
```

`perl -g` is the same as `perl -0777` with Perl's version >= 5.36.

```
COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS:
- '/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes'
- '/edx/src/ti-theme/edx-platform'
```

---

Check `man ascii` for `\047` aka octal representation of ascii's single quote `'`